# how to filter json object in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

How can I filter these json object? I mean I want print only patients whose id is equal to 3.

```
var patients: Array<AnyObject>? if let obj: AnyObject = manager?.responseObject as AnyObject? {
            if let pats = obj["patients"] as! Array<AnyObject>? {
                patients = pats
            }
        }
```

This is my printed variable

```
{
    patients =     (
                {
            city = "\U0411\U0430\U044f\U043d\U0445\U043e\U043d\U0433\U043e\U0440";
            district = "\U0411\U0430\U044f\U043d\U0445\U043e\U043d\U0433\U043e\U0440";
            firstname = fdfsdf;
            lastname = dsfgsdfg;
            "patient_id" = 1064;
            "patient_status" = 3;
            "register_id" = "\U0430\U043083040411";
        }
                {
            city = "\U0411\U0430\U044f\U043d\U0445\U043e\U043d\U0433\U043e\U0440";
            district = "\U0411\U0430\U044f\U043d\U0445\U043e\U043d\U0433\U043e\U0440";
            firstname = dwfw;
            lastname = dsfsdf;
            "patient_id" = 1056;
            "patient_status" = 1;
            "register_id" = "\U0443\U044399111134";
        }
}
```

Comment: `if let pats = obj["patients"] as [String:Any]{patients = pats.filter{$0.patient_id ==3}}` or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Please cast the types down as much as possible.

All types are more specific than `AnyObject`, JSON dictionaries are always `[String:AnyObject]` and JSON arrays are `Array<[String:AnyObject]>`. Use `Array<AnyObject>` only if the array contains another array or is more nested.

Filter the patients with the `filter` function.

```
var patients = Array<[String:AnyObject]>()

if let obj = manager?.responseObject as? [String:AnyObject] {
   if let pats = obj["patients"] as? Array<[String:AnyObject]> {
       patients = pats.filter { $0["patient_status"] as! Int == 3 } 
   }
}
```

Note: In Swift 3 `AnyObject` has been replaced with `Any`.